# PyQt5 show a file content in message window

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a file info.txt, and I want to show content when I click on Info.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QApplication,     QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
file=open("info.txt","r")
data=file.read()


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def showdialog(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)

        msg.setText(data)
        msg.setWindowTitle("Info")
        msg.show()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               
        textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(textEdit)

        sourceAction = QAction(QIcon('info.png'), 'More informations', self)
        sourceAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        sourceAction.setStatusTip('More info')


        self.statusBar()

        sourceAction.triggered.connect(self.showdialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&About')
        fileMenu.addAction(sourceAction)

        sourceAction.triggered.connect(self.showdialog)

        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        toolbar.addAction(sourceAction)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Summoner info')    
        self.show()



    if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Example()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

file.close()
```

The message box doesn't show the content of the file info.txt and almost instantly disappear.

Comment: You need to define it before you use it: Right now the parser gets to the symbol `showdialog` before it is defined.
Edit: Also, it should be `showdialog()` if you want to call it as a function

Comment: It still says that it's not defined....

Comment: Can you edit your question with the changes, as it currently stands, that's the reason it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `showdialog` as a method of your class `Example`.
This

```
sourceAction.triggered.connect(showdialog)
```

however, looks for `showdialog` in the local and global namespace - where it isn't defined.
Instead, connect the signal to the the method:

```
sourceAction.triggered.connect(self.showdialog)
```

Plus, you'll also have to take at least `self` as a parameter in your method. I've also added an `msg.show()` call - your messagebox will otherwise not become visible.

```
def showdialog(self):

   msg = QMessageBox(self) # use self as parent here
   # and/or keep a reference to the messagebox
   self.messageBox = msg
   # etc...

   # actually show the message box:
   msg.show()
```

**EDIT:** Added `self` as parent for the messagebox - so it's not recycled.

Comment: Thanks, but the message box doesn't show the content of info.txt and almost instantly disappear ...

Comment: I'd guess that's because your messagebox doesn't have a parent and you don't keep a reference to `msg` in your class. So the object is recycled and the messagebox destroyed. Creating the messagebox with a parent should fix that.

Comment: Check my updated answer. `msg = QMessageBox(self)` instread of simply `QMessageBox` sets `self` as the parent.

Comment: I created a new action supposed to close the program, but nothing happens.        fermer.triggered.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)